# How to click the correct item after use serachview in recyclerview with Cursor?

Tags: android, cursor, android-recyclerview, searchview

I'm using the searchview in a recyclerview. I handle all the data with a Cursor, The searchview is working fine and all seems ok. The problem is that when I do a search and I try to do a click in the row I can't get the correct data of this row. I get the data of the row that I have before to do a search. Seems that I can't get the current correct position.

That I want to do is when I do a click in the row that appear after do a search, get the correct data of this row.

Seems like when I display the data of the searchview, the recyclerview don't update the position of the rows.

Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

```
searchiew.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                displayResults(query + "*");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (!newText.isEmpty()){
                    displaySearchResults(newText);
                } else {
                    displayOldResults();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

private void displayOldResults(){ //This is the results that I get when inflate the view in the first time
        mAdapter = new ListDataRecycler(getActivity(), cursor, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private void displaySearchResults(String query) {
        Cursor cursorSearch = helpher.searchByInputText((query != null ? query : "@@@@"));

        if (cursorSearch != null) {
            mAdapter = new ListDataRecycler(getActivity(), cursorSearch, this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }
    }
```

This is my method to do click:

```
   @Override
    public void onRowClicked(View view, int position) {
        int idx = mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(view);

        if (actionMode != null) {
            myToggleSelection(idx);

            animatedContactPhoto(view);

            return;
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ConversationChat.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putInt("position", mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(view));
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) afapter and see its `getItemId` method

Comment: Hi. What do you mean exactly? In onRowClicked method? Can you provide me a bit of code of this, please.

Comment: doing a overide of getItemId(int position) have the same result. Don't work